# Choice script question when and how %1 can be used

Tags: batch-file

Hi I saw some CHOICE examples using %1 at the end like

```
Choice /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton:"%1
```

but some did not have %1 at the end. Just curious when %1 should be used ?
Appreciate any advice, please.

REVISED

```
Choice %~1 /n /c 01234ABCD /d 3 /t 20 %~2  " default is 3 after 20 secs " /m "Select Task Opton:%~2"
```

if "%errorlevel%"=="3" goto three
if "%errorlevel%"=="2" goto two

:three
echo %errorlevel%
echo This is Three
goto next

[image]

Comment: `%*` reads the commandline arguments. It is used to parameterize input from cmdline without having to hardcode the values into the script. I.e `ping %1` in a script when initiated as `myscript.cmd localhost` will assign `localhost` to `%1` which will result in`ping localhost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%1` is the first parameter provided to the batch file, so

```
thisbatch something somethingelse
```

would "set" `%1` to `something`; `%2` to `somethingelse`.

In the situation shown, it appends the parameter to the prompt-string, so

```
thisbatch /cs
```

would prompt with `Select Task Opton:/cs`.

BUT

If there is a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the closing quote and `%1` then it could add extra options to the `choice` command, so

```
thisbatch /cs
```

would make the choices case-sensitive.

Better would be

```
Choice /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton:" %~1
```

where you could use

```
thisbatch "/d 3 /t 20"
```

to specify "default to choice '3' if no response in 20 seconds". The quotes on the `thisbatch` line causes the string between the quotes to be treated as a single string. The `~` in `%~1` removes the enclosing quotes.

Personally, I'd use

```
Choice %~1 /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton:%~2"
```

where

```
thisbatch "/d 3 /t 20" " default is 3 after 20 secs "
```

would prompt with `Select Task Opton: default is 3 after 20 secs`

--- response to `start` question:

Yes - passing quotes as a start parameter is a problem.

Remember that the process `start`ed inherits a copy of the current environment, so you can put data into variables in the environment and have them copied into the `start`ed process.

Try this:

thisbat.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" (call :makechoice %parameters%
 ) else for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%b in ('set %1 2^>nul') do if /i "%%b"=="%~1" call :makechoice %%c
echo result is %errorlevel%

goto :eof

:makechoice
Choice %~1 /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton:%~2"
goto :eof
```

And a test/demo

thatbat.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "parameters="/d 3 /t 20" " default is 3 after 20 secs ""
set "altparameters="/d 1 /t 25" " default 1 in 25 secs ""
set "altparameters2="/d a /t 37" " default a in 37 secs ""
START "title" "thisbatch.bat"

start "anothertitle" "thisbatch.bat" altparameters
```

so if you don't provide any parameters to the `start`ed process, then that process uses the value in `parameters` that were in its inherited environment, and if you do provide the name of a variable as the argument, then `thisbatch` gets the value from the inherited variable whose name was supplied as the argument.

Comment: Is my revised script correct ?

Comment: Choice %~1 /n /c 01234ABCD /d 3 /t 20 %~2  " default is 3 after 20 secs " /m "Select Task Opton:%~2"    Is my revised script correct ?

Comment: No. `Choice %~1 /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton:%~2"` when run in a batch file like `thisbatch "/d 3 /t 20" " default is 3 after 20 secs "` would be executed as  `Choice /d 3 /t 20 /n /c 01234ABCD /m "Select Task Opton: default is 3 after 20 secs "`. The prompt would be `Select Task Opton: default is 3 after 20 secs ` and the default would be `3` which is the 4th character in the choice-options string `01234ABCD` (hence `errorlevel` will be `4`). The default would be taken as it the `3` button was pushed if the user does not respond within `20` seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I got what you meant now. It gives me more flexibliity to create batches with default choice option.

Comment: I want to adopt your script to one of my master choice to run in separate new window but it did not run. My code is   START "" "this batch.cmd" "/d 3 /t 20" " default is 3 after 20 secs "   I believe the quotes are not properly lcoated !  Any idea how to correct it ?